LYX top window with file etc. Kubuntu24.04LTS
I have lost the file pull down menu and alike that appear on the top of lyx opening page. I can not use save as or other features. How can I get back the top list

Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the support of Lyx?

Have you tried  View → Toolbars → Standard?

Yes I tried and only got icons not File, Edit, etc.
